# UITextField keyboard not dismissing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITextField` in it and I'm trying to dismiss the keyboard when I click away or the view is dismissed. However, when I call `resignFirstResponder()`, the keyboard still doesn't dismiss and I'm not quite sure why. Here's my code:

```
class MessageViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var messageTextField : UITextField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        messageTextField.frame = CGRectMake(10, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height-50, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width-80, 40)
    messageTextField.delegate = self
    messageTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    messageTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.view.addSubview(messageTextField)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        ...
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        println("Touched")
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
        let messageFrame = messageTextField.frame
        let newY = messageFrame.origin.y - keyboardSize!.height
        messageTextField.frame = CGRectMake(messageFrame.origin.x, newY, messageFrame.size.width, messageFrame.size.height)
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        var keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
        let messageFrame = messageTextField.frame
        let newY = messageFrame.origin.y - keyboardSize!.height
        messageTextField.frame = CGRectMake(messageFrame.origin.x, newY, messageFrame.size.width, messageFrame.size.height)
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why the keyboard isn't dismissing? I added the UITextField to the view programmatically as opposed to using storyboard. Does that make a difference?

Comment: use return [textField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: use TapGesturerecognizer

Comment: @AshokLondhe I used both self.view.endEditing(true) and textField.resignFirstResponder(). Neither worked.

Comment: @user1998511  debug your app and see the delegate method get called or not..

Comment: @AshokLondhe my delegate method does gets called

Comment: self.view.endEditing(true) skip this line and try

Comment: I don't see how skipping that line would help?

Answer (score 4):

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
```

confirm protocols

```
messageTextField.delegate=self
```

set  delegate

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool  
    {
        messageTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
```

Use this code..

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate     did you conform protocols?

Comment: what other protocols are there besides UITextFieldDelegate and setting messageTextField.delegate = self?

Comment: Can you please tell difference between these two objects `messageTextField` and `textField`. Why are you paste same code that already used by questioner.

Comment: textField is the parameter for the textFieldShouldReturn function. Think of it as a placeholder for whatever UITextField you're trying to "return" from. messageTextField on the other hand is the explicit variable name for the UITextField that is in the project.

Answer (score 1):

The following is how I did for that problem. I hope this method solve your problem.

textfield

```
@IBOutlet var userID : UITextField!
```

function.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!)-> Bool
{   userID.resignFirstResponder( )
    return true
}
```

In your desired function, you need to write this syntax.

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject)
{
    userID.resignFirstResponder( )
}
```

This is in ViewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidLoad( )
{
    userID.delegate = self;
}
```

I cannot comment on the previous user. That's why I write this one. 
I hope this gives you idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
   //textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return false
}
```

check `delegate` add into your `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

[how-to-dismiss-uitextfields-keyboard-in-your-swift-app](http://www.codingexplorer.com/how-to-dismiss-uitextfields-keyboard-in-your-swift-app/)

This might helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

@vijeesh's answer will probably work, and the logic is almost correct, but it is technically wrong if you ever use more than one UITextField. textField is the UITextField parameter that is passed when textFieldShouldReturn is called. The problem is, you're just declaring:

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

Your program doesn't know what UITextField you're referring to. Even though you may only have one textField in your program, and you know that it's your messageTextField, the program still doesn't know that. It just sees "textField". So you have have to tell it what to do for each UITextField in your program. Even if you have just one. This should work:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == messageTextField {
        messageTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple.
first you add Tap Gesture

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handle:")
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

in function handle

```
func handle(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){
view.endEditing(true)
}
```

so you can dismiss keyboard when you click outside UITextField